# UTF-8 in clobval query and sax parser

Tags: java, oracle, utf-8, special-characters, saxparser

I am using the below oracle query to retrieve the data from Oracle database. My column type is `XMLTYPE`:

```
select a.xmlrecord.getClobVal() xmlrecord "+" 
from" + " " + tablename + " a
```

The reason why I am using `getclobVal()` is we have a limitations in `getstringVal()` query where we cannot retrieve more than 4000 characters in Oracle.

Currently I am extracting the data from database and sending it directly to sax parser. Below is the piece of code which I'm using

```
 while (orset.next()){
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(orset.getCharacterStream("xmlrecord")); // to retrieve getClob
        InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
      is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    sp.parse(is, handler);

    }
```

The problem is we are unable to retrieve UTF-8 characters even though I am encoding UTF-8 in my code.

Kindly assist.

Comment: did you used UTF-8 while saving data too ? Also, what do you mean by **unable to retrieve UTF-8 characters** ?

Comment: Yes sabir, used UTF-8 while saving the data. We are unable to set encoding for characterstream..Any idea ?..

Comment: what errors you get?

Comment: i am getting as "'D41C)", but my original value is in arabic "الشركة"

Answer (score 0):

Your `reader` is a `CharacterStream` and not a `ByteStream`. Encodings are ignored for character stream and has an effect only on byte streams so if you wish to incorporate encoding , create your `BufferedReader` for byte stream instead of character stream ,

I am quoting two sources below,

[Class InputSource](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/index.html)

> The SAX parser will use the InputSource object to determine how to
>   read XML input. If there is a character stream available, the parser
>   will read that stream directly, disregarding any text encoding
>   declaration found in that stream. If there is no character stream, but
>   there is a byte stream, the parser will use that byte stream, using
>   the encoding specified in the InputSource or else (if no encoding is
>   specified) autodetecting the character encoding using an algorithm
>   such as the one in the XML specification. If neither a character
>   stream nor a byte stream is available, the parser will attempt to open
>   a URI connection to the resource identified by the system identifier.

[setEncoding](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#setEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)

> This method has no effect when the application provides a character
>   stream.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is working fine with characterstream resultset.

The above piece of code returned UTF-8 characters and the problem is due to the Windows machine doesn't support UTF-8 character set.

Finally we installed a package for Arabic character(UTF-8) in windows PC and the issue is resolved.